# multilingual webapp in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, internationalization

what is the best practice to design database and application for multilingual website in ruby on rails?

I know that rails already has I18n api but what is the best way to design database?

Comment: I feel this is going to be downvoted for being too "open"

Answer (score 0):

For translating database content, you want the Globalize 3 gem.

An excellent Railscast can be found on the subject here : http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3